# Is it a bad idea to supplement Itras By's freeform style of gameplay with dice?

Tags: homebrew, norwegian-style, itras-by

I'm a pretty experienced TTRPG player planning on running an Itras By campaign with a slightly modified setting. Several of my players are new to RPGs, and a couple are slightly experienced.

While I really, *really* love the setting of Itras By, the system feels perhaps too freeform for new players, and I'm worried that the Resolution Cards won't provide the players enough of an opportunity to utilize their characters' skills, as they have all have the same chance at succeeding in a task, regardless of the task at hand or their experience with that task. I do love the Chance Cards, and was planning to keep them.

My working plan is to replace the Resolution Cards with something like a FATE system, in which the game's existing character creation is supplemented with skills from FATE, and fudge dice are used to see how situations are handled. Maybe more in line with the original setting, I might also get a pack of FATE cards, though I don't have experience with those and I'm not sure if they're any good.

My brother had an alternate solution, in which the cards in the Resolution Deck change based on a character's skill in a situation.

Does anybody have experience modifying Itras By like this? Would it detract from the surrealism of the setting, or create a disconnect between gameplay and setting? Would the FATE cards help make up for this? Am I completely wrong in the first place about this potential failing of the Resolution Cards?

Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Hi Carolyn, welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. Currently this reads like you are suggesting homebrew mechanics for a system. If so it helps to give a single clear explanation of the rules you are planning to use. Then detail the feedback you are looking for. See [How to ask a good homebrew review question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8121/48759) for more information. Good luck and happy gaming!